# Where Can I Find a 12v Solder-less Breadboard Power Supply?

Tags: power

I am trying to find a 12 V input and 12 V output breadboard power supply but I can't find one. I am making an Arduino-controlled lock but the Arduino cannot power the lock strike by itself so I need to use a separate power supply. The link to make things clearer:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-RFID-Door-Lock/#step0

Comment: If your input is 12V then why do you need a 12V output?

Comment: To be a able to use it with a breadboard, I am using a 120vac to 12vdc switching adapter to power the breadboard power supply.

Comment: What's wrong with just using wires?

Comment: I want to separate the power from the outlet to positive and ground.

Comment: ... What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: I plug the switch adapter into the outlet and into the breadboard power supply. From there i can use 12v of power from my breadboard since it connects into the sockets of the breadboard.

Comment: I can't find a power supply that outputs 12v

Comment: That's odd as you said you already using a 12v switcher.  Apparently you are misusing "power supply" to describe some other function.  Be more specific about what this mystery item should do - imagine for a minute you are managing an engineer who will create this new invention from scratch: what is the requirement?

Comment: Do you want a DC barrel jack on a board with wires or breadboard pins?

Comment: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/114 this is basically what i want, but i want it to output 12v.

Comment: There is nothing special about a power supply that connects to a breadboard directly versus one that connects via wires.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams so does that mean that a dc barrel jack would work?

Comment: Provided you connect a regulated power supply to it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thank you, if you put that as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: Could that be a typo in the first sentence of your question, and you meant a _120v_ input, 12v output supply? That would explain a lot of the confusion that followed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special about a "breadboard power adapter" that isn't served by a normal regulated supply. Simply use wires or a barrel jack or some other connector to connect any regulated supply to the breadboard as desired.

Answer (score 0):

They sell 5V/3.3V breadboard supplies on eBay for $3-$5 shipped from China. Buy one and rewire/modify it to bypass the voltage regulator